# State and country codes like ISO 3166-1 and ISO 3166-2?

Tags: usa, standards, county, state

I know there are two specs that essentially catalog the entire planet into the political region/subregions, with internationalization

- [ISO-3166-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1) which has 2-letter, 3-letter, numeric, and country names.
- [ISO-3166-2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-2) which has subdivision names and their abbreviations

So,

- Is there any open distribution of these? I know you can buy the spec, but I know you can also implement it into a product. Are there any products that leak the spec out? Are there any draft distributions of `ISO-3166-[12]` like there are with the SQL spec?
- Is there anything that rivals these specs that is also internationalized that I can use in an open source product?

Answer (score 4):

Here's a number of options:

- [ISO 3166-2 subdivisions JSON](https://github.com/olahol/iso-3166-2.json/blob/master/iso-3166-2.json)
- [ISO 3166-1 country lists merged w/ UN Geoscheme regional codes in JSON, XML, CSV](https://github.com/lukes/ISO-3166-Countries-with-Regional-Codes)
- [ISO 3166-2 NPM Package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/iso-3166-2.json)
- [CSV of ISO 3166-2](https://www.ip2location.com/free/iso3166-2)
- [List of all countries with their 2 digit codes (ISO 3166-1)](https://datahub.io/core/country-list/r/country-list_zip.zip)
- [Linked ISO 3166-2 Data](https://old.datahub.io/dataset/iso-3166-2-data)
- [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1)